# Why __shared__ memory causes error in calculations

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory

I had a bug in my cuda kernel code. I managed to know where is the bug and fix it, but it would be nice to know what caused it exactly.

I am saving two numbers (p_x, p_y) [3D array XY sizes] in a shared memory 2 element array {**shared** size_t size_p[2]}

If i use kernel function parameters p_x, p_y directly in my kernel code, everything is fine. If i save them in the shared memory and start using them, the bug appears again.

First code: kernel executing with wrong answer.
Second code: kernel executing with right answer.
Third code: minimal driver

I am using the dev_array class from [here](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/dev_array_A_Useful_Array_Class_for_CUDA/), everything is correct about it.

`

```
__global__ void element_wise_add(
    float* p,
    size_t p_x,
    size_t p_y,
    size_t p_z,
    float* B,
    size_t B_x,
    size_t B_y,
    size_t B_z,
    unsigned int path_x,
    unsigned int path_y,
    unsigned int path_z,
    const float scalar) // try making this in __shared__ memory
{

    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


    __shared__ size_t size_p[2], size_B[2];

    if (index == 0)
    {
        size_p[0] = p_x;
        size_p[1] = p_y;
        size_B[0] = B_x;
        size_B[1] = B_y;
        
    }
    
    __syncthreads();
    if (index == 100)
        printf("%d == %d == %d == %d", p_x, p_y, size_p[0], size_p[1]);
    if (index < size_p[0] * size_p[1] * p_z)
    {
        //Get ijk indices from each index
        unsigned int k = index / (p_x * p_y);
        index -= k * p_x * p_y;
        unsigned int j = index / p_x; //maybe here yLen 
        index -= j * p_x;
        unsigned int i = index / 1;

        


        
        
        B[arrayIndex(i+path_x, j+path_y, k+path_z, B_x, B_y)] += scalar*p[arrayIndex(i, j, k, p_x, p_y)];

        //index = arrayIndex(i + path_x, j + path_y, k + path_z, size_B[0], size_B[1]);
        //int index_B = arrayIndex(i, j, k, size_p[0], size_p[1]);

        //atomicAdd((B + index), scalar * p[index_B]); // make arrayIndex function a preprocessor micro for speed
    }
```

`

Second kernel:

```
__global__ void element_wise_add(
    float* p,
    size_t p_x,
    size_t p_y,
    size_t p_z,
    float* B,
    size_t B_x,
    size_t B_y,
    size_t B_z,
    unsigned int path_x,
    unsigned int path_y,
    unsigned int path_z,
    const float scalar) // try making this in __shared__ memory
{
        
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    


    if (index < p_x * p_y * p_z) 
    {
        //Get ijk indices from each index
        unsigned int k = index / (p_x * p_y);
        index -= k * p_x * p_y;
        unsigned int j = index / p_x; //maybe here yLen 
        index -= j * p_x;
        unsigned int i = index / 1;

    

        B[arrayIndex(i+path_x, j+path_y, k+path_z, B_x, B_y)] += scalar*p[arrayIndex(i, j, k, p_x, p_y)];

        
    }
}
```

minimal driver:

`

```
__host__ __device__ int arrayIndex(int x, int y, int z, int height, int width) {
    return x + y * height + z * height * width;
}


void print_3d_serial_array(float* ptr, size_t X, size_t Y, size_t Z);


void kernel_sample_driver_()
{
    const int Nx = 10;
    const int Ny = 10;
    const int Nz = 10;

    const int px = 10;
    const int py = 2;
    const int pz = 2;


    float a[Nx * Ny * Nz], b[px * py * pz];

    for (size_t k = 0; k < Nz; k++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Ny; j++)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < Nx; i++)
            {
                a[arrayIndex(i, j, k, Nx, Ny)] = i + j + k;

            }
        }
    }
    for (size_t k = 0; k < pz; k++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < py; j++)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < px; i++)
            {
                b[arrayIndex(i, j, k, px, py)] = 1000 * (i + j + k + 1);
            }
        }
    }


    print_3d_serial_array(a, Nx, Ny, Nz);
    print_3d_serial_array(b, px, py, pz);


    gpu::dev_array<float> d_a(Nx * Ny * Nz);
    gpu::dev_array<float> d_b(px * py * pz);

    d_a.set(a, Nx * Ny * Nz);
    d_b.set(b, px * py * pz);


    dim3 threadsPerBlock;
    dim3 blocksPerGrid;
    threadsPerBlock.x = Nx * Ny * Nz;
    threadsPerBlock.y = 1;
    blocksPerGrid.x = ceil(((double)(Nx * Ny * Nz)) / (threadsPerBlock.x));

    element_wise_add << <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> > (d_b.getData(), px, py, pz, d_a.getData(), Nx, Ny, Nz, 0, 1, 1, 1);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    d_a.get(a, Nx * Ny * Nz);

    print_3d_serial_array(a, Nx, Ny, Nz);

}



void print_3d_serial_array(float* ptr, size_t X, size_t Y, size_t Z)
{
    for (size_t k = 0; k < Z; k++)
    {
        int len = 0;
        printf("Array( : , : , %02d) =\n\n", k);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Y; j++)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < X; i++)
            {
                printf("%3.1f , ", ptr[arrayIndex(i, j, k, X, Y)]);
                }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        for (size_t l = 0; l < X; l++)
        {
            std::cout << "-";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << std::endl;
        }
}
```

`

I removed the bug but I want to be able to save p_x and p_y into the **shared** memory to speed up calculations.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about the right or wrong answer. What input do you use, what output do you actually get with the different versions, what do you expect?

Comment: float*p and float* B are very large arrays (100*100*500 and 600*600*600). So the result of the long simulation is plotted in paraview not printed. When I use the shared memory version, the results are incorrect. Nothing changes but the use of shared memory

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose. Your statement "the results are incorrect" is not sufficient. Without more detail we don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. The error is in this code section:

```
int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


__shared__ size_t size_p[2], size_B[2];

if (threadIdx.x== 0) // was {if (index == 0)}
{
    size_p[0] = p_x;
    size_p[1] = p_y;
    size_B[0] = B_x;
    size_B[1] = B_y;
    
}
```

because I am executing a grid, and the shared arrays are local to threadBlocks, only the first thread block (with index == 0) has its shared array initialized.

changing the condition to `if (threadIdx.x == 0)` fixed the issue.

This bug would not be present if I run the minimal driver, because the calculations are only one threadBlock ... (Nx*Ny*Nz < 1024)

Comment: Instead of showing the wrong code and explaining whyt you changed, I suggest to show the fixed code. A comment at the changed line would help to spot the change.